# PyTorch custom model Android

Tags: android, pytorch

I am trying to replace the model provided to the PyTorch `HelloWorld` example as provided [here](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/HelloWorldApp), with my custom trained model. The custom trained model is hosted [here](https://github.com/OverEuro/deep-head-pose-lite). I export the model using the following script:

```
import torch.nn
import stable_hopenetlite

model = model = stable_hopenetlite.shufflenet_v2_x1_0()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model/shuff_epoch_120.pkl', map_location="cpu"), strict=False)
model.eval()
example = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

I copy the `model.pt` into the `assets` folder of the PyTorch `HelloWorld` example and run it but instead of getting a `[1, 66]` shaped Tensor, I'm getting a `[1, 1000]` shaped Tensor. Could anyone please explain where I'm going wrong or what do I need to do to get the correct output?

Comment: are you sure you replaced `model.pt`? can you verify the new model is running and not the old one?

Comment: @Shai yes I deleted and replaced them many times just to be sure but it still gives me the wrong output

Comment: Your problem is probably not here but in the Android code part. You can verify this by:
`p,q,r=model(example); print(p.shape)`

Comment: @PiyushSingh yes and that's is what I'm asking. How to get the correct output in the Android code?

Comment: The path to save is different in the tutorial example and in your code above. Could that be the problem? traced_script_module.save("app/src/main/assets/model.pt")

Comment: Also what happens when you run p,r,q=model(example); print(p.shape)?

Comment: @Barracuda can you print the model to see its last layer whether it needs to produce 66 or 1000? I know it should be 66 but the loaded model may be different